# Как сгенерировать docx файл Django?

Tags: python, django, docx, python-docx

Мне нужно, чтобы на сайте выводилась ссылка на скачивание генерирующегося docx файла, но, облазив форумы, я так и не понял, как это реализовывать.
Хочу, чтобы при генерации файла в шаблон документа вместо {{ }} вставлялись данные из бд.
Как реализовать это, используя python-docx или docxtl? что нужно прописывать в views.py, urls.py и в html шаблоне, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку файл скачался на компьютер?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Сформируй html страницу с нужными полями, шаблон адаптируй для печати.

Поставь на сервер libreoffice и конвертируй

```
mkdir inhtml
mkdir outdocx

wget -O ./inhtml/doc.html https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278903/Как-сгенерировать-docx-файл-django

soffice --headless --infilter=writerglobal8_HTML \
     --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" --outdir ../outdocx/ ./inhtml/doc.html
```